# Javax-Persistance : Entity does not have a primary key using Java records

Tags: java, hibernate, java-14, jpa

I am trying to create a entity class using Java record, but I get the error message
"Entity does not have primary key" although I assigned an ID annotation.

```
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.time.LocalDate;

    @Entity
    public record Agent (
            @Id
            String code,
            String name,
            LocalDate date,
            String workingArea,
            String country,
            String phoneNumber,
            boolean licenseToKill,
            int credits,
            byte[] picture)
          {}
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: As far as I know, JPA does not support records (for details why, please see [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/java-records-jpa-hibernate/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `record` cannot be used as Hibernate entity because it breaks the requirements of an entity according to JPA specification. Make it `class` and use `@Immutable` annotation instead:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
public class Agent
```

Answer (score 0):

Just clearing the answer for completeness (although @Turning85 and @gkatiforis have already provided correct explanation):

According to the JPA specification, an entity must follow these requirements:

- the entity class needs to be non-final,
- the entity class needs to have a no-arg constructor that is either
  public or protected,
- the entity attributes must be non-final.

However, as explained by this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/java-records-jpa-hibernate/), the Java Record type is defined like this:

- the associated Java class is final,
- there is only one constructor that takes all attributes,
- the Java record attributes are final.

But records are a good fit for a DTO projection, which is often used as a read-only representation of the data stored in your database.
more info - https://thorben-janssen.com/java-records-hibernate-jpa/

Comment: A record can have more than one constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`Entity` class internally use setter methods to set the data. As record are immutable. It only contain

- fields
- all-args constructor
- getters
- toString
- equals/hashCode methods

and not `setter` methods. So we can't use `record` as entities.